# Customizing the unsubscribe URL in Amazon SNS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services

When Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) sends an email notification, it puts an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the message. The link points to amazonaws.com and it says that for any support the subscriber must contact "contact@amazonaws.com".

This can cause confusion for end users who receive the notifications because they would expect to get the notification from the software or web site that they know and use and not from Amazon.

Is there a way to customize the "Unsubscribe" message and link of an Amazon SNS message?

Comment: I find SNS to be terrible for this sort of thing, because of the reasons you describe. I ended up using SES or SendGrid for all emails to users.

Comment: The SNS email option is not really intended for notifying genuine "end users" from the general public -- if it were, then it would support html messages, and attachments, but it doesn't.  Note that subscribers also have to click a similar link in order to initially authorize their subscription.

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't be customized. If you want to control the experience better, best to roll your own solution (which can still run on AWS), but not use the SNS generated emails...